# Different Breush-Pagan test results from bptest() and check_heteroskedasticity()

Tags: r, performance, model, regression

I was testing for heteroskedasticity in a model and tried two functions for doing Breush-Pagan tests:
lmtest::bptest()
performance::check_heteroskedasticity()

From the documentation of check_heteroskedasticity, it says, "This test of the hypothesis of (non-)constant error is also called Breusch-Pagan test (1979)."

Still, the functions gave different p-values. check_heteroskedasticity was only function that reported a p-value less than 0.05

Am I misunderstanding/incorrectly applying these functions for them to have different results?

An example demonstrating the inconsistency I'm observing

```
m <- lm(mpg ~ hp + cyl, data = mtcars)

performance::check_heteroscedasticity(m)
lmtest::bptest(m, studentize = TRUE)
lmtest::bptest(m, studentize = FALSE)
```

```
> performance::check_heteroscedasticity(m)
Warning: Heteroscedasticity (non-constant error variance) detected (p = 0.041).

> lmtest::bptest(m, studentize = TRUE)

    studentized Breusch-Pagan test

data:  m
BP = 5.5086, df = 2, p-value = 0.06365

> lmtest::bptest(m, studentize = FALSE)

    Breusch-Pagan test

data:  m
BP = 4.4698, df = 2, p-value = 0.107
```

Comment: [This statsexchange conversation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/193061/what-is-the-difference-between-these-two-breusch-pagan-tests) might be helpful to figure out the reasons.
It seems that check_heteroscedasticity does the original (non-studentized) bp-test with fitted values.

Comment: Thanks. That post was helpful, but I don't think it clarifies to me why bptest() with "studentized = FALSE" still produces different results.
In the linked conversation, car::ncvTest() is also mentioned. I tried it and it produces the same results as performance::check_heteroskedasticity(). 
If I use one independent variable in my regression, bptest() with studentized=FALSE also matches those results -- but not if I have an additional independent variable.

Answer (score 2):

To extend on my comment:

`check_heteroscedasticity()` does compute the bp-test non-studentized and uses the fitted values for the potential explanatory variables.

`bptest()` as a default uses the same explanatory variables as in the regression model you specify (and studentizes as well). So in order to have matching results we need to use the fitted values of the model in `bptest()` as well.

To show this using data from the `faraway` package (as in the linked thread in the comments):

```
library(faraway)

mdl = lm(final ~ midterm + hw, data = stat500)

performance::check_heteroscedasticity(mdl)                            # p ~ 0.42
lmtest::bptest(mdl, studentize = FALSE)                               # p ~ 0.61
lmtest::bptest(mdl, studentize = F, varformula = ~fitted.values(mdl)) # p ~ 0.42
```

So now we got the same results.
However when I run this with the `mtcars` data, I get an error in the auxiliary regression fit of `bptest()` and I cannot really figure out why.

```
m <- lm(mpg ~ hp + cyl, data = mtcars)

performance::check_heteroscedasticity(m)                          # p ~ 0.041
lmtest::bptest(m, studentize = F, varformula = ~fitted.values(m)) # error
```

> Error in lm.wfit(X, y, wts) : 0 (non-NA) cases

Maybe somene else want to chime in on this.